# CodeIgniter: How to know if $this->load->database(); did connect?

Tags: codeigniter

If I configure my CI application to use database for session handling, if a session userdata returns false, I can assume that the user's session has expired.

But what if the actual reason that it returned false was because the database connection was not established successfully?

Comment: If you can't connect to the database, then there's no way you're going to be able to use their session data...

Answer (score 5):

By default CodeIgniter will fatal error if the database is loaded and cannot connect, but if you have:

```
$db['local']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

then it won't tell you. You can turn debugging off in general but still react to a failed load by doing this:

```
if ( $this->load->database() === FALSE )
{
   exit('THE END IS NIGH!');
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. I'm using db groups and maybe the logic is slightly different there, but load->database("group", TRUE); seems to return a mysql object even if it fails to connect. Instead, I had to turn autoinit off and check if db->initialize() is false instead.

Comment: Yeah, this answer definitely doesn't work. If the database is already loaded successfully, subsequent calls to load the database will always return FALSE.

Comment: Correct. Don't call it multiple times? :)

Answer (score 3):

I test all I found and nothing wokrs, the only way I found was with dbutil checking if database exists.

```
$this->load->database();
$this->load->dbutil();

// check connection details
if( !$this->dbutil->database_exists('myDatabase'))
    echo 'Not connected to a database, or database not exists';
```

Comment: Your answer helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

CI throws

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
```

or something similar on connection failure

Comment: That only happens if you have db_debut = TRUE in your database.php.

Comment: Is there any way to get more detailed error message? For example password wrong, port closed etc.