# Detect when CodeIgniter fails to connect to a Db

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I've got a CI instance which connects to a Db and checks permissions before serving pages. If the page isn't accessible to the current user, it redirects to a login page.

The login page, obviously, has permissions set so that it's accessible to all users.

After a recent glitch, the database server came back up on a different IP address (thank you Amazon, EC2). This resulted in CI being unable to check permissions for any page - including Login. Since the code assumes anything other than a Yes is a No, it redirected to Login. The result was an infinite redirect loop.

While this exact problem shouldn't happen again (Static elastic IP), I'd like to detect when the Db connection is down and handle it appropriately.

I've seen [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3785984/156755) which is what I'm trying to achieve but I'm not explicitly loading the database in any controllers, it's in the autoload config file.

So,

How can I query the state of the Db connection from inside CI? Do I have to run a useless query and check if I get results back or is there a more elegant solution?

Edit: The check is currently being performed in a hook:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'AuthHook',
                                'function' => 'ValidateCredentials',
                                'filename' => 'auth.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Since the code assumes anything other than a Yes is a No, it redirected to Login."*

So therefore you only need to alter the login logic function to specifically check for a DB connection (and thus still auto-load the database).

Use something like

```
 $result = $this->db->conn_id;
```

Comment: This looks like the test I was after - presumably this will be null/unset if there's no connection?

Comment: actually it will be false - so you could do "if ( ! $this->db->conn_id))

Answer (score 6):

You can extend the controller and load the database in its constructor:

```
    class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
             if ( $this->load->database() === FALSE )
             {
                //do something
             }
         }
     }
```

All your controllers will inherit the new controller.

Comment: That seems like a nice way to go (and I can see other functionality being squeezed in there too). It may, however, not be possible to do that way as the permissions check is currently being done inside a hook. I didn't mention it as I didn't think it would be relevant. I'll update the Q with more info.

Comment: You can insert the `ValidateCredentials` code into `My_Controller`'s constructor, after `parent::__construct();` The functionality will remain the same if all your controllers extend `MY_Controller`

Comment: Thanks - This is something I'm likely to do in future but for the moment, I think @Laurencai's answer is a little closer to the question I asked (although yours seems to be closer to what I need longer-term). Thank you