# Code Igniter ExceptionHandling for NuSOAP WebService

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, exception, nusoap

I'm developing web service using PHP-CodeIgniter with NuSoap Library.

I wan't to return JSON string from my webservice.

Let say I have a **user registration** web service.

If user registration succeed, I want my service return:

```
{"code":1,"message":"Registration Success"}
```

If there is an error, I want my service to return:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Registration Failed"}
```

But my problem is when an error occurred, code igniter handle its own error & showing its own error page like this:
[image: Error from code igniter]

[image: Error on client side]

so I cannot return 'Registration Failed' for my web service.

How to handle error in code igniter? I mean like this:

```
try{
  $this->myModel->registerUser();
  return json_encode(array("code" => 1, "message" => 'Registration succeed'));
}
catch(Exception $e){
  return json_encode(array("code" => 0, "message" => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL for the `spr_InsertUpdateUser()` function. You should try debugging it to see why it's failing. It seems like the 4th parameter which is letter `a` is the issue because the SQL in the function is expecting a date

Comment: Yup, there was an error on my procedure exactly as you said. But how to handle that error & catch it on my code so I can return `json_encode(array("code" => 0, "message" => $e->getMessage()));`?

Comment: Why handle it? Fix it so that you are not passing an `a`. If you would like to turn off DB debugging, which I highly recommend for a public production environment, then go into the `config` folder and turn off the `db_debug` setting inside the `database.php file`. Please check out the reply from Pascal Kriete in this post on [CI Forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/76524/)

Comment: I wanna handle the error, coz my web service cannot be accessed if CI response its own error page. I attach the screenshot above.

Comment: It is much better to validate the data before passing it to the DB function and return a descriptive error code of the failure such as `if(!is_proper_date($date){return {"code":2,"message":"Registration failed: incoreect date format supplied"};});`

Comment: That's a good idea, but how if there's an error on my DB connection or DB failure or any other un-handled exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41882/discussion-between-willy-lazuardi-and-monkeyzeus)

Comment: My apologies but I am currently busy, you can look into proper error handling within CI's excellent [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html) or check out this post for ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776738/codeigniter-how-to-know-if-this-load-database-did-connect . I have actually extended CI with my own primitive PDO Class so I am not precisely familiar with CodeIgniters' implementation. Best wishes!