# Connecting two databases in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, codeigniter

I am conneting two databases in codeigniter. My database.php configuration is as follows.

```
    $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'dvrs',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['orcl_db'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'mvrs',
    'password' => 'mvrs',
    'database' => 'MVRS',
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Now I am autoloading the default database, and loading the orcl_db in the respective model on demand using

```
$this->orclDB = $this->database->load("orcl_db", TRUE);
```

I am connecting to both dbs and running queries successfully.

I need to make sure that the oracle server is available before connecting to it and display proper error messages if the server is not available / not responding.

What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: $db['default']['default'] = array(...); $db['default']['orcl_db']  = array(...); like this

Comment: database usage is working fine. there is no need to change the config file as I am connecting to both dbs successfully. I only need to make sure that the oracle server is available before connecting.

Comment: Refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776738/codeigniter-how-to-know-if-this-load-database-did-connect

Comment: May I know where(I mean in which file) you are loading the oracle server?

Comment: I am loading it in a Model's constructor

Comment: You are doing right way

Comment: everything is working fine except I want to make sure that the oracle server is available. How to avail this? :(

Comment: @SyedRizwanAli if the connection fails to oracle server, CI will throw an error. use `try  catch .......` statement  and throw your own error if connection fails. This might work?

Comment: @mdamia tried it, but actually if the server is down a timeout error occurs, which apparently cannot be caught through try catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the code to ensure it.

```
$this->orclDB = $this->load->database('orcl_db', TRUE);

        if (!$this->orclDB ->initialize()) {
            $response["status"] = false;
            $response["message"] = "Oracle DB is not available.";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn off db debugging, which throws fatal error when db connection fails, use `$db['orcl_db']['db_debug'] = FALSE;` in your database config file. Then you can check if database is loaded like this:

```
if ( $this->load->database('orcl_db') === FALSE )
{
   // do whatever you think is appropriate, but do not panick
}
```